# What's the best practice to save all data from multiple step pages?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I need help.
I have a web application in Yii2 with multiple pages step-by-step, that aggregate any data to one model. Want to know how to aggregate all data: with multiples AR models or in one AR-model with not-required columns. What's the best practice for it?

For example. I have a "Customer" ar-model. In first step i have "personal info" page with fields: first name, last name, etc. In second step i have another group of data, such as "contact info": email, phone etc.

What's the best practice for it: create one "Customer" AR-model with all not-required columns (phone, first_name, last_name, email) or create two AR-models, with required columns, such as CustomerPersonalInfo and CustomerContactInfo with related required columns.

Thank you very much for any help. Sorry for my language.

Comment: You shouldn't model your database based on form, since forms are changing all the time. You should model database to store data in most practical and sensible way, and then create separate layer (like form models) that will handle these forms.

Comment: Ok. Thx for recommendations...went the same way.